# function places html outside of intended span tags

Tags: php, wordpress

Here you'll see I have two functions set up for "fb_comment_count" and "my_post_gallery": [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4cqfnDe3).

Around line 123, you'll see that I am using "fb_comment_count". The trouble is that the generated markup does not place the comment count number within those `span` tags but rather somewhere else.

Below is the generated markup to show you what I mean. All of the comment counts (the `a` tags) are pushed to the top and the `span` tags (`<span class="comment-number"></span>`) are empty. Can anyone help me figure out why this happens?

```
<section class="tab_content" id="tab1" style="display: block;"> 
    <a title="Comments for Photos" href="http://mysite.com/test/photos/#comments">0</a>
    <a title="Comments for Photos" href="http://mysite.com/test/photos/#comments">0</a>
    <a title="Comments for Photos" href="http://mysite.com/test/photos/#comments">0</a>
    <a title="Comments for Photos" href="http://mysite.com/test/photos/#comments">0</a>
    <a title="Comments for Photos" href="http://mysite.com/test/photos/#comments">0</a>
    <a title="Comments for Photos" href="http://mysite.com/test/photos/#comments">0</a>
    <a title="Comments for Photos" href="http://mysite.com/test/photos/#comments">0</a>
    <a title="Comments for Photos" href="http://mysite.com/test/photos/#comments">0</a>
    <style type="text/css">
        #gallery-1 {
            margin: auto;
        }
        #gallery-1 .gallery-item {
            float: left;
            margin-top: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 33%;           }
        #gallery-1 img {
            border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
        }
        #gallery-1 .gallery-caption {
            margin-left: 0;
        }
    </style>
        <!-- see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php -->
        <div class="gallery galleryid-818" id="gallery-1"><div class="gallery-item"><span class="photos-comment-number-wrap"><span class="comment-number"></span></span>
            <span class="gallery-icon">
                <a title="fff" href="http://mysite.com/test/photos/attachment/fff/"><img width="150" height="150" title="fff" alt="fff" class="attachment-thumbnail" src="http://mysite.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/fff-150x150.gif"></a>
            </span></div><div class="gallery-item"><span class="photos-comment-number-wrap"><span class="comment-number"></span></span>
            <span class="gallery-icon">
                <a title="plate with 5" href="http://mysite.com/test/photos/attachment/plate-with-5/"><img width="150" height="150" title="plate with 5" alt="plate with 5" class="attachment-thumbnail" src="http://mysite.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/plate-with-5-150x150.jpg"></a>
            </span></div><div class="gallery-item"><span class="photos-comment-number-wrap"><span class="comment-number"></span></span>
            <span class="gallery-icon">
                <a title="reference" href="http://mysite.com/test/photos/attachment/reference/"><img width="150" height="150" title="reference" alt="reference" class="attachment-thumbnail" src="http://mysite.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/reference-150x150.png"></a>
            </span></div><br style="clear: both"><div class="gallery-item"><span class="photos-comment-number-wrap"><span class="comment-number"></span></span>
            <span class="gallery-icon">
                <a title="test" href="http://mysite.com/test/photos/attachment/test/"><img width="150" height="150" title="test" alt="test" class="attachment-thumbnail" src="http://mysite.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/test-150x150.jpg"></a>
            </span></div><div class="gallery-item"><span class="photos-comment-number-wrap"><span class="comment-number"></span></span>
            <span class="gallery-icon">
                <a title="test-24" href="http://mysite.com/test/photos/attachment/test-24/"><img width="150" height="150" title="test-24" alt="test-24" class="attachment-thumbnail" src="http://mysite.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/test-24-150x150.gif"></a>
            </span></div><div class="gallery-item"><span class="photos-comment-number-wrap"><span class="comment-number"></span></span>
            <span class="gallery-icon">
                <a title="test-pilot" href="http://mysite.com/test/photos/attachment/test-pilot/"><img width="150" height="150" title="test-pilot" alt="test-pilot" class="attachment-thumbnail" src="http://mysite.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/test-pilot-150x150.png"></a>
            </span></div><br style="clear: both"><div class="gallery-item"><span class="photos-comment-number-wrap"><span class="comment-number"></span></span>
            <span class="gallery-icon">
                <a title="its-hackin-christmas" href="http://mysite.com/test/photos/attachment/blah"><img width="133" height="133" title="its-hackin-christmas" alt="its-hackin-christmas" class="attachment-thumbnail" src="http://mysite.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/blah.jpg"></a>
            </span></div><div class="gallery-item"><span class="photos-comment-number-wrap"><span class="comment-number"></span></span>
            <span class="gallery-icon">
                <a title="who-wants-to-party" href="http://mysite.com/test/photos/attachment/who-wants-to-party/"><img width="133" height="133" title="who-wants-to-party" alt="who-wants-to-party" class="attachment-thumbnail" src="http://mysite.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/who-wants-to-party.jpg"></a>
            </span></div>
            <br style="clear: both;">
        </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP function use `return` instead of `echo`. so, for *example*, instead of having this on line 26:

```
echo $comments;
```

change it to:

```
return $comments;
```

Same thing goes for other lines with `echo`.

Comment: That worked by getting the numbers within the `span` tags like I wanted but it got rid of the numbers completely on another part of the site where I'm calling the function directly like this      `<span class="comment-number"><?php fb_comment_count(); ?></span>` Is there another way?

Comment: In the other places you can echo the result: `<span class="comment-number"><?php echo fb_comment_count(); ?></span>` (notice the `echo` added in that line)